# How can I reliably pass base_url from Codeigniter to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, base-url

I am working on a basic blog application with **Codeigniter 3.1.8** and **Bootstrap 4**.

The posts have comments. Of course, there is a *delete comments* functionality. It operates via (jQuery) AJAX:

```
$('.delete-comment').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var baseUrl = window.location.origin;
    var deleteUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var commentsCount = Number($("#comments_count").text());

    if (confirm('Delete this comment?')) {
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + '/dashboard/comments/delete/' + id,
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(deleteMsg) {
                commentsCount = commentsCount - 1;
                $('tr#' + id).fadeOut('250');
                $("#comments_count").text(commentsCount);
                $('#comment_delete_msg').text("The comment has been deleted");
                $('#comment_delete_msg').slideDown(250).delay(2000).slideUp(250);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In certain conditions, there is a problem with the way I get the *base URL* in JavaScript: `var baseUrl = window.location.origin;`. It only works if the blogging platform is running in the root of the website (domain).

If instead, I have it running in `https://mywebsite.com/blog` I need to use:

```
var baseUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/' + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] + '/';
```

Since this is a platform intended to work in both the situations above and possibly others, I need a more "universal formula" for the variable `baseUrl`.

Could I "borrow" it from Codeigniter? If yes, how?

Comment: Set correct *route*, also, I'm not using base_url during building *url* option for AJAX request. It's useless part.

Comment: what's wrong with `baseUrl = '<?php echo base_url();?>'`?

Comment: @Vickel 's comment is, actually, the only logical way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare global variable in footer/header/page[view file] something like

```
<script>var baseUrl = '<?= base_url(); ?>';</script>
```

Use `baseUrl` anywhere you need.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a hidden input in footer like

```
<input type="hidden" id="base_url" value="<?php echo base_url();?>"/>
```

Then you may able to use it in JS like

```
$('.delete-comment').on('click', function(evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
var baseUrl = $('#base_url').val();
....
```